# Exponential form of an element in SU(4)

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, matrix-exponential, unitary-matrices

I am studying quantum computation and have been stuck in a simple question that may look silly to experts of mathematics.
Every two-qubit operation is expressed as an element of $SU(4)$.
All the textbooks and papers in physics I saw state that **every** element $U \in SU(4)$ can be written of the form

$$U = \exp \left( -i \sum_{j, j'=0,x,y,z, (j,j')\ne(0,0)} t_{j j'} \sigma_j \otimes \sigma_{j'} \right)$$

with real parameters $t_{j j'}$ for the Pauli matrices $\sigma_j \, (\sigma_0 \equiv I_2)$.

I am wondering if it is true for $U = \pm i I_4 \in SU(4)$, which make me feel no parameter $t_{j j'}$ gives them.

I understand I misunderstand something... but I do not know what the correct theory is.

In addition, I want to know how to determine for given 16 components of an $SU(4)$ matrix whether it can be written in the exp form or not.

Comment: Well, the physics literature is probably steeped in the custom of not caring about the overall phase. If you read carefully, you may find explicit disclaimers to that effect.

Comment: Are $\sigma_x,\ \sigma_y,\ \sigma_z$ the Pauli matrices? What is $\sigma_0$?

Comment: $\sigma_j$ are the Pauli matrices. I editted the question.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\pm i I_4 = U(\pm \frac{\pi}{2}),$ where
$$
U(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
e^{it} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & e^{it} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & e^{it} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & e^{-3it} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\in SU(4).
$$

Now,
$$
U'(0) = \begin{pmatrix}
i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & i & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & i & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -3i \\
\end{pmatrix}
= i (\sigma_0 \otimes \sigma_3 + \sigma_3 \otimes \sigma_0 - \sigma_3 \otimes \sigma_3)
=: i\Sigma
,
$$
i.e. $U(t) = \exp(it\Sigma).$

Comment: That is awesome. The first sentence in my post was correct.

Comment: @qubyte. If you consider my answer to be correct, then it's good practice to mark it as such. There should be an icon for that. This makes visitors directly see that the question has an accepted answer, and they can either skip trying to answer it or use the answer. And - most important - it increases my reputation somewhat. :-)